# How can I prove the structure of this binary matrix inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, finite-fields, matrix-equations

I am studying Linear Feedback Shift Registers (LFSRs), which produce sequences of binary numbers.

One way of generating the sequence is to update the $n$-bit internal state "register" $r$ by left-multiplying it with an $(n \times n)$ binary matrix $M$ (in GF(2)):

$$
r_{k+1} = Mr_{k}
$$

The binary output sequence ($b_0, b_1, \dots$) can then be taken from any bit in $r_{k+1}$, as long as you choose the same bit for every $k=0,1,2,\dots$ (and as long as the initial state $r_0$ is not all zeros).

The particular structure of $M$ I am interested in is the [Galois (right-shift)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register#Matrix_forms) form:

$$
M=\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
c_{0} & 1 & 0 & \cdots  & 0 \\ 
c_{1} & 0 & 1 & \ddots  & \vdots  \\ 
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots  & \ddots  & 0 \\ 
c_{n-2} & 0 & \cdots  & 0 & 1 \\ 
c_{n-1} & 0 & \cdots  & \cdots  & 0%
\end{array}%
\right] 
$$

The value of $c_{n-1}$ is guaraneed to be 1. All other $c_0, c_1, \dots, c_{n-2}$ may be either 0 or 1.

I became interested in trying to calculate the initial state $r_0$, based on the observation of the first $n$ output bits $b_0, b_1, \dots, b_{n-1}$. Specifically, I am interested in the case where the output bit $b_k$ is taken from the **last** element of $r_{k+1}$.

This means that:
$$
b_0 = last\_row\{M\}r_0 \\
b_1 = last\_row\{M^2\}r_0 \\
\vdots \\
b_{n-1} = last\_row\{M^n\}r_0 
$$

So I wrote this as a matrix equation (in GF(2)):
$$
b = Br_0
$$

Where $b$ is the column vector $[b_0, b_1, \dots, b_{n-1}]^T$ and $B$ is the $(n \times n)$ binary matrix formed by stacking the last row of $M^k$ for $k=1,2,\dots,n$. Then I simply solve:
$$
r_0 = B^{-1}b
$$

When I looked at the structure of $B^{-1}$ I saw a remarkably simple pattern. It's a binary Toeplitz matrix, where the main diagonal is always 1 and the non-zero (sub)diagonals come directly from the $c_0, c_1, \dots, c_{n-2}$ values in $M$.

For example, if $[c_0, c_1, c_2, c_3] = [1,1,0,1]$ then the 1st and 2nd subdiagonals of $B^{-1}$ are 1 (because the 1st and 2nd elements of $c$ are 1):
$$
M=\left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0%
\end{array}%
\right]
$$

$$
B^{-1}=\left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1%
\end{array}%
\right] 
$$

Similarly, if $[c_0, c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4] = [0,1,1,0,1]$ then the 2nd and 3rd subdiagonals of $B^{-1}$ are 1 (because the 2nd and 3rd elements of $c$ are 1):

$$
M=\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0%
\end{array}%
\right] 
$$

$$
B^{-1}=\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1%
\end{array}%
\right] 
$$

I checked this for some millions of cases and it didn't fail. I feel like I am missing a simple explanation for why this must always be true. Have I maybe over-complicated matters by involving a matrix inverse? Can this result be proved to hold in general?

**EDIT:** I have written a (matrix) proof based on "State Recovery with LFSR Shifting, Method B" described at [this link](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/1114.php). However, this was several pages of work, so I would really like to see if there is a more direct way of proving this result.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but if you just want to compute $r_0$ in terms of the $b_i'$s, there is a simpler way. For such matrix it is not difficult to see that that the characteristic polynomial is $X^n-c_0X^{n-1}+\cdots-c_{n-2}X-c_{n-1}$. So, applying Cayley-Hamilton and you $r_0$ yields $b_{n-1}-c_0b_{n-2}-c_{n-2}b_0-r_0=0$, taking into account that $c_{n-1}=1$. Thus, $r_0=b_{n-1}+c_0b_{n-2}+\cdots+c_{n-2}b_0$.

Comment: @GreginGre This sounds like the kind of simple solution I was expecting, but I'm not sure how to evaluate your equation. $r_0$ is an $(n \times 1)$ vector, but the $b_i$ and $c_i$ are scalars. I tried reading the Wikipedia page on Cayley-Hamilton, but it's quite far beyond my level of understanding. Could you clarify?

Comment: sorry, i mixed up $c_0$ and $r_0$... For your information; Cayley Hamilton says that a matrix $M$ satisfies its characteristic polynomial. Here, it means that  $M^n-c_0M^{n-1}-c_{n-2}M-I_n=0$ (since $c_{n-1}=1$). But it is not useful to solve your problem. Anyway, I'm pretty sure that your problem has a nice solution, but I have to think more about it...I'll think about it this weekend and I keep you posted.